# Disable ValidatesOnDataErrors if IsEnabled property is False WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, textbox

I have a program in MVVM pattern and I have a View which contains some objects, one of them is a Value TextBox which ValidatesOnDataErrors when writing a text in it.

Also I have a Binding to its IsEnabled property which changed on the ViewModel by some conditions I made.

I want be able to eliminate ValidatesOnDataErrors (make it False) when the binding propery of IsEnabled is False, How I can do that?

```
<StackPanel>
   .....

   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" IsEnabled="{Binding isValueFieldEnable}"/>

   .....

</StackPanel>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can change entire `Text` binding in `DataTrigger` in `TextBox`'s style when `isValueFieldEnable` becomes `false`.

Comment: Simply your `IDataErrorInfo` should return "no error" if your `isValueFieldEnable` is false

Comment: @IlVic you are right, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Il Vic suggests this validation logic should be implemented in the view model class.

You don't change the `ValidatesOnDataErrors` property of the binding in the view. Instead, you should make sure that your view model is always in a valid state and return no errors for the data-bound `Value` property whenever the `isValueFieldEnable` property returns false.

The binding in the view is always the same. It is your view model that is supposed to define whether the `Value` property is set to a valid value. And the property should Always considered to be valid when the `isValueFieldEnable` is false. That's your validation logic. And this should be implemented in your view model class, not in your view.